# Reduction modulo homomorphism from Z_m to Z_n

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Consider positive integers $m>n$ and function $\phi (x)$ from $Z_m$ into $Z_n$ equal to the remainder when $x$ is divided by $n$.
Is $\phi$ a homomorphism? I.e is $\phi(x+y)=\phi(x)+\phi(y)$ for every $x,y \in Z_m$

Fraleigh asks a number of these questions with concrete $m,n$ that can be proved by inspecting cases but this is messy and
it seems that if $n|m$ than $\phi$ is a homomorphism but I am not sure how to prove it in the general case. I can prove that if gcd(m,n)=1 that it is not a homomorphism.

Comment: How do you choose $x$ in its congruence class?

Comment: The smallest representative. For example, Z_12 to Z_3, \phi(23)=\phi(11) = 11 mod 3 = 2

Comment: The remainder is not well defined unless $n|m$.

Comment: So supposing we assume n|m how can it be shown the homomorphism property follows? The other questions seems to ask the same thing but doesn't answer it or I don't see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider such a map $\phi:\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$; we claim that $\phi$ is a homomorphism if and only if $n\mid m$.

- **If:** Suppose that $n\mid m$. We have $$x\equiv \phi(x)\pmod{m}\iff m\mid x-\phi(x)\implies n\mid x-\phi(x)\iff x\equiv \phi(x)\pmod{n}$$ Implying that $\phi(x+y)\equiv x+y\equiv \phi(x)+\phi(y)\pmod{n}$ $\Box$
- **Only if:** Such a homomorphism $\phi$ is clearly surjective, since $$\phi(k)\equiv k\cdot\phi(1)\equiv k\pmod{m}$$ It follows from the First Isomorphism Theorem that $\mathbb Z_m/\text{ker}(\phi)\cong \text{im}(\phi)=\mathbb Z_n$, and in particular that $n=|\mathbb Z_n|$ divides $|\mathbb Z_m|=m$ $\Box$

Comment: Thanks. The forward direction is clear now.  I already knew it was necessary since otherwise, $Ker(\phi)$ which contains multiples of n and must be a subgroup of $Z_m$ will not have a order which divides the order of $Z_m$ causing a contraction by Lagrange's Theorem.

Comment: @Rafi Hello! Would that ring homomorphism be unique?